# Page numbering in a bold format

Tags: page-numbering

I have been trying to put the page numbers in bold throughout the whole document but i cannot seem to get it right. I tried to renewcommand the pagenumbering command but it did not work. `\renewcommand{\pagenumbering}{\bfseries}`.

I was also looking in other webpages but could not find it.  Can someone please let me know how is this properly done?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) so we can see which documentclass you using and which page styles you set up.  As standard `\pagenumbering` just sets up whether the page number is numeric or a roman numeral.  Formatting in e.g. a footer should be done in a different way.

Comment: With the KOMA-Script classes you just need `\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\bfseries}`.

Comment: Are the bold page numbers limited to headers and footers? What about the page numbers in the table of contents? What about page numbers in references (`\pageref`)?

Answer (score 1):

(My previous answer was probably wrong, so I deleted it and am giving this one, which is better.)

Andrew Swann is absolutely right that we need a minimal working example; but let's see one way you could get this done.  Assuming you're using the `article` class, and your page number is centered in the footer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\cfoot{\textbf{\thepage}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
Hello, world!
\end{document}
```

This will do what you want, but it will leave page numbers elsewhere alone.  It will also work through commands that change the page number's format, if you're using a document class which has such commands, such as `book`.

The `fancyhdr` documentation is quite good, and will give you a great deal more information about how else you can format running headers and footers.